# Monitoring with Sharktap and Time Sync functionality

Tags: networking, ethernet, systemd-timesyncd

I have code that works for network monitoring *OR* Time Sync.

When I have both ethernet connections, I can only network monitor. The connection runs through a sharktap so the time sync functionality does not work.

The system necessitates two ethernet connections. One is connected to the sharktap with an Ethernet-to-USB (so timesync functionality no longer works) and the other is connected to the Pi's ethernet port but will not synch time.

I'm building a system to allow power cycling and technicians to remove a USB with logged data that has correct time stamps.

Comment: Time synchronisation is done by `systemd-timesyncd` and controlled by `timedatectl` that uses `sntp` to go out to an internet timeserver and set the time. It wakes up periodically to check the time is still sync'd. You can replace that with `ntpd` or `chrony` as long as you **explictly** disable `systemd-timesyncd` with `timedatectl`.